# Freshly installed Puppet Environment not working, CSR not matching public key

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-16.04

I want to play around with puppet, so I set up a small test environment, consisting of 4 VMs

- pfSense: Router
- Windows Server 2012 R2: DNS, DHCP
- Ubuntu Server 16.04: Puppetmaster
- Ubuntu Server 16.04: Puppet agent

DNS is set up correctly, it answers all forward- and reverse lookups correctly.

Here is the set of command I executed on both of the ubuntu vms (base configuration)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install -y vim openssh-server ntp
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

vi /etc/hostname (set to puppet / puppetclient)
sudo reboot now

wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

And then on the master:

```
sudo apt-get -y install puppetserver
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running enable=true
sudo service puppetserver restart
```

The puppetserver-service is running nicely (after assignign 6GB of RAM to the VM ;))

On the client:

```
sudo apt-get install puppet-agent
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
```

On the client, I then do a:

```
puppet agent --server puppet.puppet.intra --waitforcert 60 --test
```

This is answered by

```
Error: Could not request certificate: The CSR retrieved from the master does not match the agent's public key.
CSR fingerprint: 82:F5:08:CC:98:8A:D1:8F:EC:3D:B0:F7:5B:EB:43:FC:FC:0D:95:30:E8:6F:7F:81:9E:1B:02:CB:A4:01:0E:50
CSR public key: Public-Key: (4096 bit)
Modulus:
    ...
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)

Agent public key: Public-Key: (4096 bit)
Modulus:
    ...
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)

To fix this, remove the CSR from both the master and the agent and then start a puppet run, which will automatically regenerate a CSR.
On the master:
  puppet cert clean puppetclient.puppet.intra
On the agent:
  1a. On most platforms: find /home/administrator/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl -name puppetclient.puppet.intra.pem -delete
  1b. On Windows: del "\home\administrator\.puppetlabs\etc\puppet\ssl\certs\puppetclient.puppet.intra.pem" /f
  2. puppet agent -t
```

Of course, I executed the proposed troubleshooting steps, without result. I further checked:

- I can open port 8140 on the server
- the time settings to match
- both machines have the correct hostname set and are resolved by the dns correctly

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Christian

```
Edit

I just realized something: It seems like the problem only occurs when I try to run puppet as a different user than I installed it with.
I wanted to run puppet agent -t as root with sudo on an OS X client and got the error message described earlier. When I run puppet as the user I installed it with, the error doesn't occur.

How can I fix this?
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: Use sudo all the time or login as root directly (not recommended though)**

Okay, seems like this was my fault: I am not 100 percent sure, but I maybe installed puppet as root (via sudo), did the CSR as a normal user and afterwards tried to run it as root again.

It seems like I should have used sudo / root all the time because after I removed the certificates from the client and server like this:

```
    To fix this, remove the CSR from both the master and the agent and then start a puppet run, which will automatically regenerate a CSR.
    On the master:
    puppet cert clean puppetclient.puppet.intra
    On the agent:
    1a. On most platforms: find /home/administrator/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl -name puppetclient.puppet.intra.pem -delete
    1b. On Windows: del "\home\administrator\.puppetlabs\etc\puppet\ssl\certs\puppetclient.puppet.intra.pem" /f
    2. puppet agent -t
```

And then redid the CSR as root, everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Yes, I did notice this also with puppet agent. If run as unprivileged user it gladly tries to do things which are not productive at all and lead to confusing error messages. They should really add an --unprivileged switch and complain if an unprivileged user tried to run puppet agent without it.